# parse xml files with python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

Let's assume that i have couple of xml files.
Assume that the first file is the base and the next files are the overrides (like update to the base file).
I want to write a program that get lists of files (updates) and create a final xml with all the data.
I succeed to read each file but i don't know how to combine them together.

The original xml:

```
<Base>
<Module ID = "Module1"
    Prop1 = "A"
    Prop2 = "B"
    Prop3 = "C"
/>
<!-- XML comment -->
<Module ID = "Module2"
    Prop1 = "D"
    Prop2 = "E"
    Prop3 = "F"
/>  
</Base>
```

An update:

```
<!-- XML comment -->
<Override>
<Module ID = "Module1"
    Prop2 = "B_ov"
    Prop4 = "ZZ"
/>
<!-- XML comment -->
<Module ID = "Module2"
    Prop1 = "D_ov"
    Prop5 = "F"
/>  
</Override>
```

Final xml file should look like:

```
 <!-- XML comment -->
<final>
<Module ID = "Module1"
    Prop1 = "A"
    Prop2 = "B_ov"
    Prop3 = "C"
    Prop4 = "ZZ"
/>
<!-- XML comment -->
<Module ID = "Module2"
    Prop1 = "D_ov"
    Prop2 = "E"
    Prop3 = "F"
    Prop5 = "F"
/>  
</final>
```

The code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def main():
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('xml', nargs='+')

a=parse_xml("Base.xml")
print (a)

b= parse_xml("Override.xml")
print (b)

def parse_xml(path):
    return {m.attrib.pop('ID'): m.attrib for m in ElementTree.parse(path).findall('Module')}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would help if you also provided an example of your xml files too

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem. You must build iterate over the override document trees, and for each override, find the place in the base that it overrides and make the appropriate change; then when you've processed all the overrides write out the updated base tree.

Comment: I know the the algorithm, just don't know how to implement it with python. I don't know how to access to the values in the xml file and check them. Can you give me an example how to print Prop1 for instance?

Comment: @IdoGabovich, the tags `<Base>` and `<Override>` should have closing tags. Update you inputs to make them valid

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution (without `<!-- XML comment -->` items):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

base_tree = ET.parse('Base.xml')
base_root = base_tree.getroot()
override = ET.parse('Override.xml').getroot()

base_root.tag = 'final'   # set new `root` tag

for m in base_root.findall('Module[@ID]'):

    # finding the `overridden` Module element with respective `ID`
    repl_el = override.find('Module[@ID="{}"]'.format(m.get('ID')))
    base_attrs = dict(m.items())
    base_attrs.update(repl_el.items())
    for k,v in base_attrs.items():
        m.set(k, v)

print(base_tree.write('output.xml', encoding='unicode'))
```

The final `output.xml` contents:

```
<final>
<Module ID="Module1" Prop1="A" Prop2="B_ov" Prop3="C" Prop4="ZZ" />

<Module ID="Module2" Prop1="D_ov" Prop2="E" Prop3="F" Prop5="F" />
</final>
```

Comment: Can you explain findall('Module[@ID]') and find('Module[@ID="{}"]? I don't understand the meaning of the '@'.

Comment: @IdoGabovich, `@` - points to attribute name. In your case - `@ID` - attribute `ID` value